# Android text message software

Tags: android, sms, mms

On smartphones you have different apps. One for your text messages provided by manufacturer of your phone. There is an instant messaging software like Skype or Whatsapp. I'm looking for an app which combines all these services in one.

- Text messages
- Multimedia text message
- Instant messaging
- Send photos, videos and sound
- Choose the receiver
- One flow for all send and received messages for each communication partner

Does any app exist which fulfills all of these requirements?

Comment: Is there only hangouts? No other alternatives available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question sounds like a description of **[Hangouts](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.google.android.talk)**, after SMS/MMS got integrated a while ago:

- Send/receive SMS/MMS
- chat or even make video calls (even with up to 10 friends)
- photos, videos, sound can of course be send using MMS, but at least photos can be shared from *Hangouts* directly
- "one overview", if I understand you correctly, should match the feature announced as *See what you talked about in the past, including shared photos and your video call history*

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Example screenshots from the app's playstore page (click images for original size)</sup>